# Is this an existing design pattern or not?

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns

In my company, we have a project built upon this pattern. I would like to know if this is an existing and acknowledged design pattern, a combination various patterns or just a convenient coding solution to a problem.

```
interface IService <TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest, TResponse : IResponse
{
     TResponse ProcessRequest(TRequest request);
}

public class ConcreteService : IService<ConcreteRequest, ConcreteResponse>
{
    public ConcreteResponse ProcessRequest(ConcreteRequest request)
    {
        // Do some stuff to create the ConcreteResponse object
    }
}
```

And then in a web service action:

```
[WebMethod]
public ConcreteResponse SomeService(ConcreteRequest request)
{
    // Do some validations...

    // And then...
    var service = new ConcreteService();
    return service.ProcessRequest(request);
}
```

**Note:** I have seen other real world projects following a similar approach.

Comment: I see some inheritance and generics, but I don't know what pattern you might be thinking about.

Comment: Without actual code or an explanation what this is supposed to do, this looks a lot like the good old "overengineering" pattern.

Comment: @larsmans - I suspect this approach has more to do with providing a level of version tolerance to external clients.

Comment: @larsmans It is used in a web service project to create the appropriate Response to any Request that is made by the user. We have a class that inherits from IService for every web method in the web service (20+ web methods) and it's made this way to keep the logic off the web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - it is very close to the Request-Response pattern and it is quite common in SOA applications, or in scenarios where you present a public interface to external callers.

The main advantage to this pattern is that it is highly version tolerant.

Normally, if I want to add a new argument to an existing method on an interface, it breaks the compatibility of that interface - because the signature of the method has changed. Clients compiled against one version, cannot call another - even if the new field is optional, or if an old field has been obsoleted and can be ignored.

Using this apporach, the signature of the method (`ProcessRequest` in your example) itself stays the same, but the request type (`ConcreteRequest` in your example) now has an additional property on it. Generally speaking most serialization/deserialization is tolerant of this (or can be configured to be tolerant of this); if the property appears in the data but not on the type it is being deserialized to, it will be ignored. Conversley if the property doesn't appear in the data, but does on the instance then the instance will just have a default value (null, zero or whatever).

So I can add/remove parameters from the method in a way that I wouldn't be able to do if I had a normal method with a list of arguments. As you extend and evolve a public interface, this can become a very powerful tool.

Having said all of that - it is only useful *if you need it*. I've seen it used in scenarios where this brings no benefit too.

Comment: Does the Request/Response Pattern describes only the use of these two objects to exchange information in a SOA or it also refers to the way these objects interact with each other and their life-cycle?

Comment: From memory - I would say that it describes the idea that you have a single "ProcessRequest" method, and that you pass different concrete types in. You may have a GetUserInfoRequest with a corresponding GetUserInfoResponse and a DeleteUserRequest with a corresponding DeleteUserResponse. You then have all calls going to one mthod, but the concrete request type dictates the actual call itself. As mentioned above, the request/response objects can then be changes over time without breaking everything. You can also add new "methods" without changing the public method sig, just the types it accepts.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a variety of the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). In terms of messaging this is a [Message Translator](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageTranslator.html) pattern.

> The Message Translator is the messaging equivalent of the Adapter
>   pattern described in [GoF]. An adapter converts the interface of a
>   component into a another interface so it can be used in a different
>   context

Comment: I second that it's a Message Translator, but only if ` // Do some stuff to create the ConcreteResponse object` is some simple code that can be considered to only do translations.

Comment: Yes you right. But from other point of view we can look at this like - `service as message translator` it translates request into response, but this is not about messag transformation it is more SOA so I admit Message Translator not quite fit in this example

Comment: @DaveBall It is possible that the ProcessRequest method has complex logic. It's not a simple transformation from Request to Response.

Answer (score 2):

I think this a normally usage of interfaces, but it's close to [Request-Response pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response). To be better, you can use [an abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or [dependency injection pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), depends on what you want.

Comment: Can you explain how would those other two patterns make the code “better” in this case?

Comment: The first one, depending of his goal, how many types of concretes responses he want, this can be useful. And the second one in the "translation" of the interface to concrete class, for exemple using enterprise library unity, to change only in one place the "translation", even to change in all classes that he use the "manually" translation like a cast when he create a new object of his concrete class.